# How can I print input data?

Tags: c, linked-list

As a practice for final exam, I am practicing a linked list. But now I am stuck at printing input data on my code. I made this linked list and want to print input data. But my code does not print anything.

What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int a,b ;
    struct Node* next;
}NODE;

void makenode()
{
    int a;
    int b;

    printf("enter the name : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("enter the sur name : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    NODE* node1=malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    node1->a=a;
    node1->b=b;
    node1->next=NULL;

    return node1;

}

void printList()
{
    NODE *ptr=NULL;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d", ptr->a);
        printf("%d", ptr->b);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    NODE *head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    head->next=NULL;
    makenode();
    printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makenode()` return type is `void`, it should be `NODE*`.

`printList()` does not fech the list so it can't know what to print, moreover `ptr` is `NULL` so it never enters the print loop.

**Fixed code with comments:**

[**Live demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/HyBkmCITL)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int a, b;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

NODE* makenode() { //return type NODE*

    NODE *node1 = malloc(sizeof(*node1));

    printf("enter the name : ");
    scanf("%d", &node1->a);
    printf("enter the sur name : ");
    scanf("%d", &node1->b);
    node1->next = NULL;

    return node1;
}

void printList(const NODE *ptr) { //pass NODE* ptr as an argument

    int i = 1;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Node %d\n", i++);
        printf("a: %d\n", ptr->a);
        printf("b: %d\n", ptr->b);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

```
int main() {

    //make first node
    NODE *head = makenode(); //assing node

    // add one more node
    NODE* node = makenode();
    head->next = node; //chain second node

    printList(head); //print nodes

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**On another note:**

It's kind of strange that the names are `int` and not strings.

You could do:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJVxGCUaI)

```
typedef struct Node {
    char name[100]; //names as strings
    char surname[100];
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

NODE* makenode() { //return type NODE*

    NODE *node1 = malloc(sizeof(*node1));

    printf("enter the name : ");
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", node1->name);
    printf("enter the sur name : ");
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", node1->surname);
    node1->next = NULL;

    return node1;
}

void printList(const NODE *ptr) { //pass NODE* ptr as an argument

    int i = 1;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Node %d\n", i++);
        printf("Name: %s\n", ptr->name);
        printf("Surname: %s\n", ptr->surname);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

//...
//main is the same
```

Comment: what does it mean "%99"? and why didnt you use %s? When I used %s, there were no output shown on my screen.

Comment: @최재욱 `" %99[^\n]"` specifier takes a maximum of 99 chars, spaces included,  or stops when it finds a newline character, (added to input when you press enter), this is because the container is 100 chars in size and we don't want it to overflow.

Comment: @최재욱  `"%s"` takes a single word, it stops when it finds a space and it can overflow. Note that you need to add a space before % so that white spaces on the `stdin` buffer are discarded (`" %s"`).

Comment: one last question! how can I use your code line" head->next = node;" ?? I ve spent almost 2 hours to understand adding node, but still confused of it..

Comment: @최재욱 Every struct has a pointer `struct Node *next;`, the line you mention makes that pointer point to the newly created node thus chaining the 2 nodes, `head` points to `node`, `node` is now the tail and it's pointer `next` is NULL so you know this is the end of the list, if you want to add another node to the end of the list you would do `NODE* newnode = makenode();` and then `node->next = newnode;` now `next` of `node` is pointing to `newnode` and `newnode`'s `next` points to NULL. Note that the NULL is assigned to the pointer `next` on the function `makenode()` to each newly created node.